# jQuery Cycle, 100% width, image centered vertically, window resize issue

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-cycle

The html code:

```
<div id="rotatorholder">
    <div id="slide1" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide3" class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#rotatorholder {
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#rotatorholder .slide {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
#rotatorholder #slide1 {
    background: transparent url('http://swiatlemmalowane.pl/tmp/test.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;
}
#rotatorholder #slide2 {
    background: transparent url('http://swiatlemmalowane.pl/tmp/test.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;
}
#rotatorholder #slide3 {
    background: transparent url('http://swiatlemmalowane.pl/tmp/test.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;
}
```

The js code:

```
$('#rotatorholder').cycle({
    before: function () {
        console.log($('#rotatorholder').width());
        $("#rotatorholder div.slide").each(function () {
            $(this).width($('#rotatorholder').width());
        })
    }
    after: function () {
        console.log($('#rotatorholder').width());
        $("#rotatorholder div.slide").each(function () {
            $(this).width($('#rotatorholder').width());
        })
    }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    var boxwidth = $('#rotatorholder').width();
    $("#rotatorholder div.slide").each(function () {
        $(this).width(boxwidth);
    })
});
```

The problem: everything works well untill the browser window gets resized. After that .slide elements gets their width fixed, based on oryginal #rotatorholder width. I've managed to fix elements width while window resizing (second js part), also elements gets their correct new width with use of "before" in jQuery Cycle callout, but still after one second, they get to their oryginal width.

Check it out on: http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberek/Q7bAJ/

Run it with small browser width, then rescale to browser to greater width - "center" of image should still be in center and it is durning resizing, but when You stop resizing and wait for cycle to change element, somehow slide's width gets to oryginal container width.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hmmmm. I am using Chrome v25, and when I fire off the resize event the slide elements center properly. What browser are you using?

Comment: Mac, chrome 25.0.1364.172. While resizing element is centered correctly, but when You stop resizing and wait for cycle to change slide - then problem can be seen.